# Android detect movement - registerListener application crash

Tags: android

I have problems with registerListener. My application crashes and I don't know how to write registerListener properly. 
I took some of code from Internet. Actually from this site.
Here is my code:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

 // Start with some variables
private SensorManager sensorMan;
private Sensor accelerometer;

private float[] mGravity;
private float mAccel;
private float mAccelCurrent;
private float mAccelLast;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    // In onCreate method
    sensorMan = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccel = 0.00f;
    mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;                                
}         

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorMan.registerListener((SensorEventListener)this, accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorMan.unregisterListener((SensorEventListener) this);
}

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
            // Make this higher or lower according to how much
            // motion you want to detect
        if(mAccel > 3){ 
        // do something
        }
    }

}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // required method
}
```

}

As a result application crashes.

Comment: And whatis the exception?

Comment: Please post your LogCat.

Comment: Bottom answer solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to cast `(SensorEventListener)` to `Activity` type you will get cast exception you need to implement

```
SensorEventListener in your `Activity`
```

try this

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
```